# How to use Boolean logic in a mySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, syntax

How can I check if `email = '$e'` or `username = '$e'` inside my MySQL query.

Here is my MySQL query so far.

```
"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (email = '$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p'))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify you existing query so that it works even if `$e` matches username, you can do:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE (email = '$e' OR username = '$e') AND pass=SHA1('$p')
```

Comment: I'd probably look at $e in your program, though, and decide if I want to treat it as either email or username.